# How to deserialize the json array of objects to dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a Json string

```
"[{'SymptID': '" + MidID + "', 'ALvl' : '" +JawLvl + "'},
{'SymptID': '" + BckID + "', 'ALvl' : '" + PanLvl + "'},
{'SymptID': '" + SysID + "', 'ALvl' : '" + wPLvl + "'}]"
```

```
Dictionary<string, string> Symptoms =
    (Dictionary<string, string>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
        data, typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in Symptoms)
{ //do some action }
```

how can make this get keys and values with this multiple array json data... is there any other methods.

> NOTE:The question is not a duplicate
>   to [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net),
>   because json structure is different.
>
> Here we have an array of objects with 2 properties SymptID and ALvl,
>   that need to be converted to dictionary with **key SymptID** and
>   **value ALvl.**  Referred question has one object with multiple properties having corresponding values that needs to be converted to
>   dictionary with property name as key  and property value as value in
>   dictionary.

Comment: you can alternatively use the JavaScriptSerializer class (System.Web.Extensions).                                               var result = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(yourJsonString);

Answer (score 0):

you can also use json.net or fastjson opensource libraries to perform this task in a faster and efficient way than using the built in .net serializer.

json.net - http://json.codeplex.com/

fastJson - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON