# Convert JSON array of objects with specified properties to Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dictionary

I need  to convert to dictionary JSON array of objects with key "id" and value "score" properties like the following

```
[{"score":0.6990418,"id":"4833909335"},
{"score":0.8079009,"id":"4833874639"},
{"score":0.8079009,"id":"4834247506"}].
```

Dictionary keys should have values of "id" property, and  dictionary values shoud be copied from "score".

Note that it is not a deserialization, but transforming/mapping when some information not copied to target object(e.g. names of properties and potentially other properties)

I found similar question [How to deserialize the json array of objects to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534301/how-to-deserialize-this-json-string-using-dictionary) , that was incorrectly closed as duplicate of different question about deserializing different JSON object with multiple properties.
I've tried to reopen it, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I've created extension methods to allow extract pair of properties from elements of JSON array

```
  public static Dictionary< string, string> JsonArrayToDictionary( string strJson, string keyName,string valueName)
        {
            var array = JArray.Parse(strJson) ;
            var dictionary = JsonArrayToDictionary(array, keyName, valueName);
            return dictionary;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string , string > JsonArrayToDictionary(this JArray array, string keyName, string valueName)
        {
            if (array != null)
            {
                var dict = array.ToDictionary(x => x[keyName].ToString(), x => x[valueName].ToString());
                return dict;
            }
            return null;
        }


 [TestClass()]
    public class JsonHelperExtensionsTests
    {
        [ TestMethod()]
        public void JsonArrayToDictionaryTest()
        {
            var jsonArray= @"[{""score "":0.6990418,"" id"": ""ID1"" },{""score "":0.8079009,"" id"": ""ID2"" }]";
           var dict= JsonHelperExtensions.JsonArrayToDictionary(jsonArray, "id" , "score");
            dict.Count.Should().Be(2);
            dict[ "ID1"].Should().Be("0.6990418" );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Current solution for current time:

```
var jsArray = JObject.Parse(response);
var arrayDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>[]>(jsArray.ToString());
```